# Correct code for 4th differential equation

Tags: differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis, mathematical-optimization, mathematica-online

How to code and solve the following equation in mathematica.
d^2/dx^2(x^2*d^2u/dx^2)+b^2*u=0

Answer (score 4):

> code and solve the following equation in mathematica.
> d^2/dx^2(x^2d^2u/dx^2)+b^2u=0

One way is

```
ClearAll[x,u,b]
ode = D[x^2*D[u[x], {x, 2}], {x, 2}] + b^2*u[x] == 0
```

$$
b^2 u(x)+x^2 u^{(4)}(x)+4 x u^{(3)}(x)+2 u''(x)=0
$$

To solve do

```
DSolve[ode, u[x], x]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Reply to comment**

> Is it possible to transform the given equation to 2nd order ODE

I do not know of direct function in Mathematica to do this other than coding it.

But the standard way is to convert higher order ode to set of *first* order ode's. This way all derivatives are accounted for. To do this, Mathematica has direct support for this by converting to state space.

```
ClearAll[x, u, b]
ode = D[x^2*D[u[x], {x, 2}], {x, 2}] + b^2*u[x] == 0
ss = StateSpaceModel[{ode}, {{u'''[x], 0}, {u''[x], 0}, {u'[x], 
    0}, {u[x], 0}}, {{}}, {u[x]}, x]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The above contains the $A$ matrix for $u' = A u$. Which has 4 ode's since your ode is 4th order. Let the the state variables be $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4$ then to generate these ode's you can do

```
(A = ss[[1, 1]]) // MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And now do

```
vars = {x1[x], x2[x], x3[x], x4[x]}
ode1 = x1'[x] == A[[1, All]] . vars
ode2 = x2'[x] == A[[2, All]] . vars
ode3 = x3'[x] == A[[3, All]] . vars
ode4 = x4'[x] == A[[4, All]] . vars
```

This gives the 4 first order odes as

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now use `DSolve` to solve them

```
{x1Sol, x2Sol, x3Sol, x4Sol} = First@DSolve[{ode1, ode2, ode3, ode4}, vars, x];
```

In the above `x1Sol` is the same as $u(x)$ we solved at the top directly from the original ode.

```
x1Sol
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And `x2Sol` will be $u'(x)$ and `x3Sol` will be $u''(x)$ and `x4Sol` will be $u'''(x)$.

Comment: Thank you...I replaced x^2 with another function, let's say e^2x. mathematica does not give the solution

Comment: @HaidarAli Yes, Mathematica can not solve it analytically in this case with `exp(2*x)`. You might want to try numerical solution for this.

Comment: @Nasser...Sir,   Is it possible to transform the given equation to 2nd order ODE